# Why are database operations taking 10x longer on computer connected via network than on main computer? How can I make it faster?

Tags: database, sqlite, network-programming, python-3.9

Background:

Using python 3.9.

I have two laptops running Windows 10 Home. One of them is where the code is stored and shared to a network. The other is connected to the network via Wifi (please ask if that's not enough details kinda new to that stuff). Except for the problem I'm having, the code runs fine on either computer.

I have a section of the code iterate through a csv, and for each element in the csv, I insert it into an SQLite database, all with python. The code, the database, and the csv are all stored on the main (host?) computer.

The problem:

When I run the code on the machine it's stored on, it's quite fast, when I run it on the one connected via network, it's noticeably slower. I used the time module to check where in the code the slowdown was happening, and learned that it seems to happen whenever the insert function is called to store values in the database. Using the time module I also learned it's about 10x slower on the network-connected laptop.

Why does this happen? Is the laptop having to go through the network each time it accesses the database? If so, is there any way to avoid that? to make like a local database file instead and then just copy that back into the appropriate directory? Would that work? Is there an easier way to do this, or a way that's better suited for this kind of situation (i.e. the network setup)? Would preferably like to keep it as one copy of the code that could run on either machine (which is why I'm doing this in the first place).

Lmk if code would help, it's just kind of a lot and spread out, not sure which parts would be relevant.

This is the insert function in the class I made for the sqlite database:

```py
def insert(self, <rest of parameters>):
            self.cur.execute(<sqlite insert statement>)
            self.conn.commit()
```

Edit: Shortly after writing all this I figured out if I don't "commit" every time I insert, and instead just do it at the end of the iteration, the speed is basically the same on both machines. Idk if that's enough of a solution, as I don't really know the implications of doing it that way, so I'll keep the question open until someone who knows better says differently...

Comment: SQLite and network file systems don't go together.

Comment: @Shawn could you explain why?

Comment: https://sqlite.org/useovernet.html https://sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_file_locking_problems https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: @shawn ok that's a lot to consider... thank you for the resources. I'm unsure if I should spend too much time on this though given the scope of my application. It'll only ever be used by me on the 2 computers, and never at the same time. The persistence of the contents of the DB doesn't matter too much either, as the DB is cleared every time the program is run. Would I really need to implement a server/client relationship in this scenario? Never done that before.